# D Lang File Watcher

Tags: d

I'm new to D Language and am looking for an efficient way to watch for a specific file to change.

Ultimately what I'd like is to have a watcher that waits for a file to change, and then executes a command based on the contents of the file (think of it as a plain-text queue list).

Code samples would be nice, but pointing me in the right direction would also be very helpful.

Also, this is going to run on a Linux environment.

### Update

I'm going the route of using system utilities to monitor a file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're on Linux you can use [`inotify`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), found in `/usr/include/sys/inotify.h` (on my system `$PREFIX` might differ).

> inotify is very useful in many situations where reactions on file
>   system changes are necessary. Without inotify it can be implemented by
>   periodical (or manually requested) examining files and directories.
>   But such way is slow and wastes processor time. inotify brings very
>   fast and economical method how to react on file system changes.

The only thing you have to do is translating this header into a "D header", or you use [`DStep`](https://github.com/jacob-carlborg/dstep) which might be able to translate the header for you.

You might also want to use [`fanotify`](http://lwn.net/Articles/339253/), a newer replacement for `inotify`.

Unfortunatly I don't know how you can do that on Windows, all I found is a Windows-API function: [`FindFirstChangeNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into inotify as an alternative. I'd like to keep everything under the D Lang umbrella if possible, just for learning purposes, mostly. I should have mentioned, but this will be for a Linux environment, thanks for pointing that out -- I've updated my question.

Comment: This is really a task that the OS is best equipped for, so I'd strongly recommend going the inotify route.

Comment: If there were a D-specific way to do it, it would just be wrapping the system calls in an OS-agnostic manner. So, lacking such a wrapper, the correct way to handle it is to use the appropriate system calls directly or to create such a wrapper yourself.

Comment: There is a D binding to the inotify stuff, unsurprisingly it is call dinotify, it can be found on the Dub repository.